# PHP $_SESSION use forms to increase/decrease date values keep value after refresh

Tags: php, session, post, refresh

I have this code:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['decrease_date'])) {
  $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} -1 day")) );
 }
 if (isset($_POST['increase_date'])) {
  $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} +1 day")) );
 }
 else {
  $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week')) );
 }
?>

<form action='absence.php' method='post'>
 <input type="hidden" name="decrease_date"/>
 <input type='submit' value='Previous'>
</form>

<form action='absence.php' method='post'>
 <input type="hidden" name="increase_date"/>
 <input type='submit' value='Next'>
</form>
```

As you can see I'm trying to use forms and sessions for increase/decrease dates and store this in a variable.

Now I would like refresh the page, but keep the session value that was active before the refresh-request. Right now it would either decrease or increase depending on what form was submitted because I don't have a PRG-pattern.

I could send the form submission to another file but I need the

```
else {
 $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week')) );
 }
```

because whenever a user first enter the page the value should show "Monday this week".

How would you recomend me to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just check for `$_SESSION['sess_mon']` too:

```
if( !empty( $_SESSION['sess_mon'] ) )
{

    if ( !empty( $_POST['decrease_date'] ) )
    {
        $monday_value = $_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} -1 day") );
    }
    elseif ( !empty( $_POST['increase_date'] ) )
    {
        $monday_value = $_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} +1 day") );
    }
}

// EDIT: new if-branch instead of else
if( empty( $monday_value ) )
{
    $monday_value = $_SESSION['sess_mon'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week') );
}
```

Comment: Hmm that does not seem to work. I get `Notice: Undefined variable: monday_value` after form submit

Comment: Thank's but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. Allthough I didn't get your code to work, I would assume the user would still get a message from the browser saying "would you like to send POST-data again?" but I want the page to refresh in the background without the user notice.

Answer (score 1):

You should try redirecting the page after you increase/decrease the date:

```
 if (isset($_POST['decrease_date'])) {
  $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("{$_SESSION['sess_mon']} -1 day")) );
  header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/absence.php");
 }
```

This way, on refresh the page won't be re-posted.

Also, you should separate the check to see if the session variable is set from the other `if`s, because otherwise the value will be reset with every request that is nor increase or decrease.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_mon'])) {
  $monday_value = ($_SESSION['sess_mon'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week')) );
 }
 else {
  $monday_value = $_SESSION['sess_mon'];
 }
```

Comment: That's partly what I want. Whenever a user enters the page, that is when a user clicks the "absence" link the values should be reset. Then on that page the user should be able to increase/decrease tha dates. Then if he/she leaves and comes back. The values should be reset. That's why I don't think the above code would do much difference :( But thank's anyway!